# How to show post from just two categories on Wordpress Home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Only two categories need to be showed in the homepage. Can anyone help.

Comment: link? post? image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `functions.php` file paste the below code:

I am assuming that you want to show categories from two categories which are having ids 5 and 9.

```
function kiran_home_category( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
 $query->set( 'cat', '5,9');
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'kiran_home_category' );
```

**Explanation:**

`kiran_home_category` is just a custom name for the function. That can be any name. The way it works is you attach a function to the action hook `pre_get_posts`. So before getting the posts the function `kiran_home_category` will be called. And then inside the function I am changing the query here to only load categories with ID 5 and 9

Comment: Thanks for helping but what is "kiran_home_category" ?....How will it work

Comment: This is the theme "http://demo.themegrill.com/demos/?theme=ColorNews", if you want to check

Comment: Oh. `kiran_home_category` is just a custom name for the function. That can be any name. The way it works is you attach a function to the action hook `pre_get_posts`. So before getting the posts the function `kiran_home_category` will be called. And then inside the function I am changing the query here to only load categories with ID 5 and 9

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that it worked. And if your issue is solved, please feel free to mark the correct answer. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get your posts list, and display it with the loop

Example :

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'staff,news' ) );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: Thank for answering but actually I am novice. So can you please tell where to add this code and in detail.

Comment: In the body of your home page template file, like front-page.php, or index.php, or home.php, or anything you might use.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress WP_query, **category__in** parameter used to select category with posts.

```
<?php 
      $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ),'post_status'=>'publish','orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'Asc' ) );
     if($query->have_posts()):
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; 
         endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
     endif;
   ?>
```

For more information about wordpress query [click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) , you can read more information.

Comment: yes, it show both categories. which category id is 2 and 6 .

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But in WordPress editor where to make changes and how to find out the category number?

Comment: This is the theme "http://demo.themegrill.com/demos/?theme=ColorNews", if you want to check

Comment: You can add this code any where in template, where you want to display the posts of category like front-page.php, or index.php, or home.php. when you edit the category then it will show **tag_ID=?(number)** in url. that number is category number. for eg. `http://localhost/example.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post&wp_http_referer=%2Fpneumocare.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dcategory`  in this example.you can see tag_ID=1 i.e category id=1. which is category number.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php 
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'category_name' => array('Latest News','News')  );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if($loop->have_posts()):
    ?><ul>

                <?php
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>
                    <li> <span class="date"><?php echo get_the_date( 'd F Y');?></span>
                    <h3><?php echo get_the_title();?></h3>
                    <?php echo $description = get_the_content(); ?>
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile;?>
            </ul>

    <?php endif;?>  
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank for answering but actually I am novice. So can you please tell where to add this code and in detail.

Comment: You can add this code any where in template, where you want to display the posts.

Comment: This is the theme "http://demo.themegrill.com/demos/?theme=ColorNews", if you can please see and tell

Comment: Please just copy and paste above code in any template in your theme, where you want to display, and replace category name with your category name.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following, usually in page.php or single.php or if you want a custom page for a category, you can do, category-samplecat.php..

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => array('samplecat', 'anothercat'),
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then do the usual if, while statement..

```
if($arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        // Start the loop.
            while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) : 
                $arr_posts->the_post();?>

<?php endwhile; 
endif;
```